# Facebook wall integration

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

I need to integrate FaceBook Wall on the website so I have decided to use fb.wall jquery plugin http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall/. The problem is that Access Token is expiring in 1-2 hours. I have read the documentation on the https://developers.facebook.com but cannot figure out how to get long Access Token that will last up to 60 days for this plugin and whether it is possible to make that Access Token does not expire if you log out from your facebook account. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar question, check this out:
[No access token facebook application authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189682/no-access-token-facebook-application-authentication)

The point is to get app access token.

Comment: Thanks but how I am supposed to Call the API endpoint with this plugin?

Comment: You don't need to do it, you just need to get access token (for example via graph explorer) and put it into you plugin. What do you need to set in this plugin to make it work?

Comment: Just Facebook ID and Access Token. Will it also work if I am logged out from the facebook account?

Comment: I did the same with just graph api without any plugin and it worked for me, not sure about your plugin, try it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use FB.api("/me/feed") it will return the details from user wall

Answer (score 0):

You could try this script it has can retrieve your accesss token for you http://ironlasso.com/jqueryfacebookwall-documentation/